# sharing constant variables between multiple components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, javascript-objects

What is the right way to **share a constant variable across multiple Components and Services in Angular**?

Eg:
Consider a constant variable called *CountryList* which has an array of objects, having more than 250 values key value pairs.

How do I share this constant value in multiple angular components/services?

```
const CountryList = [ 
{name:'UK', value:'United Kingdom'},
{name:'USA', value:'United States of America'},
{name:'SG', value:'Singapore'},
...
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First way (export from constants file)**

*countries.constants.ts*

```
export const CountryList = [ 
{name:'UK', value:'United Kingdom'},
{name:'USA', value:'United States of America'},
{name:'SG', value:'Singapore'}
]
```

*test.component.ts*

```
import * as coutriesConstants from '../../shared/constants/countries.constants'

@Component(
...

countries = coutriesConstants.CountryList;

...
```

**Second way (creating a service)**

countries.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CountriesService {
   countryList = [ 
     {name:'UK', value:'United Kingdom'},
     {name:'USA', value:'United States of America'},
     {name:'SG', value:'Singapore'}
   ]
}
```

*test.component.ts*

```
@Component(
...

  constructor(public countriesSrv: CountriesService){}
  // Now you can access the `countriesSrv.countryList` either in the ts file or in HTML
...
```

**Third way (inject the value)**

You can also inject the value like @jenson-button-event [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67821221/6442841) as well.

*PS: I usually go with the service approach to avoid creating properties on every component I want to share my constant data & because that way my service will be injected through my components when I needed so, it will be a little more optimized. Also injecting the value has the same advantages but I find the service way more simple and easy to scale.*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a constant and export it.

You can consider the Jhispter repo as an example ([example 1](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/src/main/webapp/app/config/input.constants.ts), [example 2](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/src/main/webapp/app/config/authority.constants.ts)). Just create a constant in appropriate folder and export it.

Also, you can consider how the Angular keep the constants ([example 1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a92a89b0eb127a59d7e071502b5850e57618ec2d/packages/upgrade/src/common/src/constants.ts), [example 2](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a92a89b0eb127a59d7e071502b5850e57618ec2d/packages/core/src/change_detection/constants.ts))

But, if you need some complex logic for your constants, try to read about the [using of `InjectionToken`](http://The%20good%20approach%20is%20to%20use%20the).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be posh you could inject them..

```js
export const Countries = new InjectionToken('Countries');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: Countries,
    useValue: [
     {name:'UK', value:'United Kingdom'},
     {name:'USA', value:'United States of America'},
     {name:'SG', value:'Singapore'}
   ]
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(Countries) public countries: any[]) { }
}
```